# France Rail Pass, seat reservations to travel within France

Tags: trains, tickets, france, bookings, sncf

I bought a France Rail Pass, "9 days within 1 month" (single country)

My itinerary is

- Paris
- Lyon
- Grenoble
- Chamonix (I want to go to Chamonix from either Lyon or Grenoble)
- Nice
- (pop out to Monaco)
- Cannes
- Marseille, back to Paris

Spending a few days at each location. Would i need to reserve seats in advance for these?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For seat reservations in France, it does not directly depends on your destinations but on the type of trains. In short, reservations are required for TGVs, some Intercités, but not on regional trains.

Other interesting things to know are that in France the amount of reservable seats for Interrail pass holders is limited, so you'd better book the sooner you can. And as @Tor-Einar Jarnbjo mentioned, reservations are not free, and [they are around 6-9 euros each](http://www.interrail.eu/plan-your-trip/reservation-guide/reservation-fees/domestic-train-reservation-fees).

Follow the [reservation guidelines on the Interrail website](http://www.interrail.eu/plan-your-trip/reservation-guide/do-i-need-reservation), it is all clearly explained.

Comment: Don't you have to pay a surcharge as well, if you want to use a rail pass on the TGV?

Comment: That's a good point, I am updating my answer

Comment: Also a good site which has useful information, http://www.seat61.com/Railpass-and-Eurail-pass-guide.htm#reservations or pay supplements with a railpass

Comment: i can't use the official website it only has EU countries. i am using RailEurope to book seats. but some of the routes like Lyon to Chamonix can't be booked because their is no direct path. guess this is going to be harder than i though.

Comment: @JinahAdam The direct or most convenient route from Lyon to Chamonix is only operated by regional trains, for which a seat reservation is not possible.

Comment: @JinahAdam I recommend you to use voyages-sncf.com for figuring your itineraries, that's one of the most complete websites (with regional trains too) for that (but booking might be easier with RailEurope)